# Create lookup field with additional columns with Provisioning Engine CSOM C#

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, office-365, csom

I have a template.xml with some columns, content types and list. I have a lookup column call Fase that comes of the Fase list and this list has a Orden Column. I need to add Orden field as an additional lookup column.

template.xml

```
<Field ID="{A35B465E-E95A-436A-8FCD-A3B3F601D2C5}" Type="Lookup" Name="Fase" DisplayName="Fase" Group="IniciativasEstrategicas" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" List="Lists/Fases" ShowField="NombreFase" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="FALSE" RelationshipDeleteBehavior="None"/>
<Field ID="{E7B67252-CF32-46DF-A90D-4A3D7F62464A}" Type="Lookup" Name="OrdenFase" DisplayName="Orden Fase" Group="IniciativasEstrategicas" ReadOnly="TRUE" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" List="Lists/Fases" ShowField="Orden" FieldRef="A35B465E-E95A-436A-8FCD-A3B3F601D2C5" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="FALSE" RelationshipDeleteBehavior="None"/>
```

The result of this xml is an additional column without list associate to it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in the dev brach works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `AddFieldAsXml` method (see the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fieldcollection.addfieldasxml.aspx)):

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
Web site = clientContext.Web;
var targetList = site.Lists.GetByTitle("YourTargetList");
var relatedList = site.Lists.GetByTitle("FaseList");
var fields = targetList.Fields;

clientContext.Load(relatedList);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var fields = targetList.Fields;
string fieldSchema = string.Format("<Field ID=\"{0}\" Type=\"Lookup\" Name=\"OrdenFase\" DisplayName=\"Orden Fase\" Group=\"IniciativasEstrategicas\" ReadOnly=\"TRUE\" List=\"{1}\" ShowField=\"Orden\" FieldRef=\"A35B465E-E95A-436A-8FCD-A3B3F601D2C5\" />",
 Guid.NewGuid(), relatedList.Id);

 fields.AddFieldAsXml(fieldSchema, true, AddFieldOptions.AddToDefaultContentType);
 clientContext.Load(fields);
 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```